# Add view to layout in specific location using Rect

Tags: android, view, android-view

I have a custom view and I want to add this view in different location of screen. I created a method which can create a Rect base on some input parameters and I want to show this object on the screen. I used FrameLayout and RelativeLayout for this purpose but FrameLayout put it in the corner and RelativeLayout doesn't show it. How can I fix it? Thanks in advance.

**Java Code:**

```
RelativeLayout deviceContent = findViewById(R.id.deviceContent);

.
.
.
private void addView(){
    ViewDevice obj = new ViewDevice(this);
    int degrees = new Random().nextInt(360);
    final Rect rect = computeChildFrame(w/2, h/2, 50, degrees, (int) Utilities.dpToPx(48));
    obj.layout(rect.left, rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom);
    deviceContent.addView(obj);
}

private static Rect computeChildFrame(final int centerX, final int centerY,
                                          final int radius, final float degrees, final int size) {

    final double childCenterX = centerX + radius
                * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(degrees));
    final double childCenterY = centerY + radius
                * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(degrees));

    return new Rect((int) (childCenterX - size / 2),
                (int) (childCenterY - size / 2),
                (int) (childCenterX + size / 2),
                (int) (childCenterY + size / 2));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After adding View in frame Layout *use **translationX** and **translationY** to position it* as the new added view is added to the view at (0,0) suppose you want to add the view at position at 100,200 relative to the frame layout then below will be ur code:

```
private void addView(){
    ViewDevice obj = new ViewDevice(this);
    int degrees = new Random().nextInt(360);
    final Rect rect = computeChildFrame(w/2, h/2, 50, degrees, (int) Utilities.dpToPx(48));
    obj.layout(rect.left, rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom);
    obj.setTranslationX(100)
    obj.setTranslationY(200)
    deviceContent.addView(obj);
}
```